# Laravel Livewire: multiple files not allowed. Docs say otherwise

Tags: file-upload, laravel-livewire

According to Livewire v2 docs (https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads#multiple-files), handling multiple files is quite simple. Set your public property to an array, and add the "multiple" attribute to your input element:

```php
class UploadPhotos extends Component
{
    ...
    public $photos = [];
    ...
}
```

```php
<form wire:submit.prevent="save">
    <input type="file" wire:model="photos" multiple>
    ...
</form>
```

But since working with files requires `use WithFileUploads;` trait, Livewire throws this exception as soon a I select the file(s) on the frontend:

> S3 temporary file upload driver only supports single file uploads. Remove the [multiple] HTML attribute from your input tag.

There's no instruction on either 2.x or 3.x docs on what else is needed. I haven't even setup the "save" method, this is happening JUST when Livewire is updating the state of the "photos" property.

(I'm aware once I'm ready to "save" I'd need to loop through the `$photos` array to store them individually in S3. This issue is happening before I have a chance to perform any backend action.)

Comment: See https://fly.io/laravel-bytes/multi-file-upload-livewire/ for some possible approaches here.

Comment: @ceejayoz good resource. But that's a lot of javascript to handle something that's purportedly built-in. Our alternate option was using manual AJAX calls, but wanted to use as much out-of-the-box features as practical. I haven't seen anyone else reference this issue, but I can see the exception being thrown from `public function startUpload` at the very top of the `WithFileUploads` trait. Docs don't mention a requirement to change temporary upload drivers to make it work.

Comment: The exception seems fairly... self-documenting.

Comment: Hahah, yes it does. It seems contradictory to the documentation though, so thinking I must be missing something simple everyone else has already figured out.